# Nativescript TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Tags: android, migration, nativescript, typeerror, nativescript-angular

I am building a mobile app with the help of NativeScript Sidekick. Following the release of Nativescript 6.0, I was forced to migrate to this newer version. This unfortunately rendered some of my application's pages inaccessible.

In search of a solution, I traversed Nativescript and general forums as well as Nativescript's posts regarding this migration. I also came across something known as [hooks](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-cli-hooks-to-nativescript-6.0) but I couldn't find anything explicitly related to the issue I am facing. StackOverflow posts seemed populated with similar issues but the solutions provided did not help me resolve the specific TypeError that has been causing my pages to crash.

Since I use Git for source control, I attempted to switch to different branches and see if I could instead continue development there. All branches warranted the same result: I could not build my project without migrating to 6.0, which led to the same TypeError.

Subsequently, I tried to set and update any package dependencies that might be causing issues as my phone's StackTrace kept referencing the file `vendor.js`. This did not help.

In a desperate attempt, I decided to completely remove any trace of Android files and my project's files, after which I did a clean reinstall of all required software using the `choco` package manager, as outlined [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win). I skipped installing an emulator as I am running everything on a physical Android device via `tns run android`. Running `tns doctor` in the terminal confirmed that everything was fine. I then proceeded to `git clone` master from a remote repository and created a local test branch via `git checkout -b test`. I once again ran my project using `tns`. Although the app builds, the same pages still crash because of the migration.

Following [these steps](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win), I opened Git Bash and executed the following:

`tns device android --available-devices` to locate my Device ID

`tns run --device fooId` to build and run the project on my selected device

Here is the TypeError and the beginning of the associated StackTrace:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tabs/tabs.js.Tabs.onLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\tabs\tabs.js:384:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:311:75
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:304:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:311:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.loadView', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:439:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:233:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js.LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\layouts\layout-base-common.js:125:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js.ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view\view-common.js:992:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.onLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:232:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js.View.onLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view\view.js:240:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:311:75
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:304:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:311:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.loadView', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:439:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:233:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js.LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\layouts\layout-base-common.js:125:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js.ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view\view-common.js:992:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.onLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:232:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js.View.onLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view\view.js:240:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:311:75
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:304:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callLoaded', file:'file:///node_modules\tns-core-modules\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:311:0
```

Comment: Please share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new project using `tns create' and keep adding all you plugins(that you using in your current project) one by one to see which one is causing the crash

Comment: @Manoj Unfortunately, I will be unable to use Playground to accurately reproduce the issue in its full extent due to the range of dependencies I have between files and the privacy of my codebase. However, Narendra's suggestion made me think of removing modules and plugins used by the affected pages to see if any particular import is the culprit. I'll be back with more info on this, but thank you both for the comments so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Nativescript 6.0 had introduced [two new components](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/tabs) which I believe are in beta testing. My project already had a custom component defined by the name of `Tabs` which conflicted with one of these and consequently caused the pages to crash. Changing the name of this component and its references throughout my project resolved the issue.